# Use Select2 with Struts

Tags: jsp, jstl, jquery-select2, struts-1

I have Struts 1 app with jsp and I want to prefill select2 (multiple) component in jsp. I have following code, which displays functional Select2 component:

```
<html:select property="codes" styleClass="myClass" styleId="myId" multiple="multiple">
    <c:forEach var="csOption" items="${codesList}" varStatus="index">  
        <html-el:option key="${csOption}" value="${csOption}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</html:select> 

...

$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
```

In the result, I want to have something like this:

```
<select ...>
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
   <option value="C" selected>C</option>
   <option value="D" selected>D</option>
   <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```

However, I want to have some values selected (we are in edit form). In case I add `selected="true"` into the `html:option` tag, there is following issue (using only `selected` does not work as well):

> Attribute selected invalid for tag option according to TLD

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Use plain HTML tags.

Comment: Write a plugin, it doesn't work with plain html